# Maven resource filtering for single file

Tags: xml, spring, maven

In pom.xml I have defined :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>xml</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Now the problem is all xml files are not filtered. Is there any possible way to filter single xml file?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I don't know why Gabor's solution did not work, but I managed to solve this way:

Firstly I removed nonFilteredFileExtension tag:

```
<nonFilteredFileExtension>xml</nonFilteredFileExtension>
```

Then modified my resources this way:

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
        <include>**/myxml.xml</include>
    </includes>
</resource>

<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.xml</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```

Now my single xml file is filtered and other is leaved untouched by filter.

Answer (score 14):

Something like this works fine for me:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>my_file.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

This documentation helps me:
[Apache Maven - Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Answer (score 10):

For the resource tag you can used includes and excludes. Just define simply a mask, which fits your single file only. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Sample:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/yoursinglefile.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: It seems that file is still not filtered. I still can see ${...} values in xml file that sits in target folder.