# use maven project information in resource files

Tags: java, maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I have directory structure like

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └──
        └── resources
            └── plugin.yml
```

Of course in the `pom.xml` itself I can get the project version using `${project.version}`, but I wonder if there's a way to inject this number into the `plugin.yml` file, its contents are:

```
name: PluginName
version: ${project.version}
description: Does plugin things
```

Is there a way to get maven to fill the `version:` value with the actual version of the project when it's built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first if the filtering capabilities of maven are enough.
See "[Apache Maven Resources Plugin/ Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)"

Inside of `<build>` add

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>plugin.yml</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Then you can use `${...}` variables in the `src/main/resources/plugin.yml` file.

Comment: How do I make it do one file instead of a whole directory

Comment: @minseong It seems to be limited to a folder, but if only one file has properties to be filtered, only that file will be modified.

Comment: I just used `<includes>` I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31788024/3310334)